# using select query doesn't work in order to retrieve the required data from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

i am using PHP and MYSQL in Wordpress in order to retrieve data from the database based on the user selection, but this query doesn't return any data.

i am using the **$wpdb** class with the **prepare()** and **get_results()**

and tried to **echo** the query in order to debug the code and it assign the right variables in order to make the comparison between the values in the database and the user's input.

## sql query :

```
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
         , i.siteNAME
         , i.equipmentTYPE
         , c.latitude
         , c.longitude
         , c.height 
         , o.ownerNAME
         , o.ownerCONTACT
         , x.companyNAME
         , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
         , y.subcontractorNAME
         , y.subcontractorCONTACT
      from site_info i
      LEFT  
      JOIN owner_info o
        on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
      LEFT  
      JOIN company_info x
        on i.companyID = x.companyID
      LEFT 
      JOIN subcontractor_info y
        on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
        LEFT JOIN site_coordinates c
        on i.siteID=c.siteID 
        where 
        i.siteNAME = %s
        AND 
        o.ownerNAME = %s
        AND 
        x.companyNAME = %s
       ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);
    echo $site_name;
     $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
             echo "query is working";
    echo "<table width='30%' ";
echo     "<tr>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo     "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
    }
```

in order to debug the code i tried to echo the sql

**echo $sql;**
where it shows the sql query with the values thats been assigned to the right variables.

**can anyone tel me where is my error that makes the query to stop an not running into the foreach loop ?**
[image: trying to debug]

[image: supposed returned data]

after i changed the query and put the values as a string in place of the **%s** i got the above  result.
i realized  what is the problem its not working because **%s** is an array , but when i put a string it works fine.
 i am converting the string to array  because i don't convert i will get this error:

```
Xdebug: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/search-info.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/index.php(17): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/search-info.php on line 245. Output triggered in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/query-monitor/collectors/php_errors.php on line 163
```

Comment: Post the query in plain text. And show the data, that you believe should be returned.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i did not understand what your asking  i will edit the question and add the supposed data that must be returned

Comment: @Strawberry what are  you asking ??

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem  what was happening that i was iterating in the query to retrieve the selected data as array.
this the code that i was using :

```
             <?php


                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                  {
                   $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                   echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                  } 
             ?>
```

i changed the iteration process from array to object , so it becomes :

```
 <?php


                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
            //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '".$site_name ->siteNAME."'>".  $site_name->siteNAME."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>
```